# I have a problem with treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm struggling with the wpf treeview.
 I need to load a list, but it is coming out the name of each object in the list, not that I'm doing wrong.
 I need a simple treeview example, carrying a ItemsSource.
My code is :

```
<my:WpfTreeView Name="tvInteracciones" Margin="10,10,10,105">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Principios activos" ItemsSource="{Binding V_VistaInteraccionPrincipioActivo}">
                            <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion_descripcion}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem>
  </my:WpfTreeView>
```

And:

```
public void LoadInteraccionesPF(List<V_VistaInteraccionPrincipioActivo> lista){
     tvInteracciones.ItemsSource = null;
                    tvInteracciones.Items.Clear();

                    tvInteracciones.ItemsSource = lista;
}
```

With the above code, I get the names of objects, not the content I want the attribute description.

What is my problem?

![This is the result scrren][1]

![enter image description here][2]

The problem remains the same then your solution which can be?

News code pics
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVJPV.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkBIz.jpg

Comment: If you don't specify a datatemplate, it will use the ToString() of the datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use item template

```
<TreeView Name="tvInteracciones" Margin="10,10,10,105">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Principios activos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion}">
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
```

[image]

Try this way...

Don't specify any itemssource to treeview item.... an itemssource should always be a collection..

```
<my:WpfTreeView Name="tvInteracciones" Margin="10,10,10,105">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Principios activos">
                            <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion_descripcion}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem>
  </my:WpfTreeView>
```

I have updated the xaml....
try this one

```
<my:WpfTreeView Margin="10,10,10,105">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Principios activos"  Name="tvInteracciones">
                            <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion_descripcion}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem>
  </my:WpfTreeView>
```

in the above code instead of giving itemssource to wpftreeview... i am giving items source to treeviewitem... just by changing the name give to wpftreeview item.....

Comment: Hello, thank you for sample, but i have an error. I have a List<V_VistaInteraccionPrincipioActivo> list;  tvInteracciones.ItemsSource = list; And i want see atribute V_VistaInteraccionPrincipioActivo.CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion_descripcion on screen. In above code, i'm use ItemsSource="{Binding Path="V_VistaInteraccionPrincipioActivo} and the text in textblock Text="{Binding CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion_descripcion}"

Comment: is it possible to post "V_VistaInteraccionPrincipioActivo" class structure and what do you want to display from that...?

Comment: i want display N descriptions the List<V_VistaInteraccion...>, the problem is the code above display the structure...

Comment: i got it by seeing your image. it is very clear that binding is happening what we have to take care is to do proper binding to show description.... that's why i am asking for full class structure..

Comment: i have do a new screen shoots, You want this?  in post CHGUV.Guia.Farmacoterapeutica.Business.HGUVHis.CFG_CAT_FAR_Interaccion is the object class

Comment: Thanks for everything, now if that works, by name failed ...
 thanks again

Comment: as I can select an item from the treeview

Comment: If that works please accept this as answer.... that will improve your acceptance percentage and i will get few credits....